# Retrieving a certain line from a text file knowing only the starting numbers (but requiring the whole line) in C++

Tags: c++, text, getline

I have a text file that I need to go through to get a specific line, I know the first 6 characters that the line contains however the current code doesn't want to stop to copy the line to another string but instead returns the last result in the list.

Here is the current code implementation:

```
std::string Type(int num)
{
    ifstream reader("TypeID.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);     //declaring the file input
    string str, replace = "failed";
    int search;

    while (getline(reader, str));
    {
        search = str.find(num, 0);
        if (search <= 0) // once find has found the string run this
        {
            replace = str; //copy current line of str to replace
            reader.close();//after string is retrieved, close stream
        }
    }
    reader.close();//after string is not retrieved, close stream

    return replace;
}
```

The "num" integer at he top can contain any number (realistically between 0-336760) the program should then go through the text file find the line staring with the number, copy the line to the replace string, close the stream and return the collected string. However this implementation doesn't stop until it reaches the end of the file and then copies the last line.

What do I have to do to grab the line that find() finds?

(my understanding of find is that it returns a number above 0 to show that it has found the required string, hence the trigger of the If statement)

example of the text document:

```
0           #System
2           Corporation
3           Region
4           Constellation
28802       Mid-grade Harvest Alpha
28803       Mid-grade Harvest Beta
28804       Mid-grade Harvest Delta
28805       Mid-grade Harvest Epsilon
```

and so on for a total of 21760 lines

Comment: You appear to be passing the int num as the first argument to string::find(). What are you expecting that to do? What you'll likely see is find() trying to find a char with the value num%256 which is probably not what you want.

Comment: There are **several** issues with your code, first address matt's issue and then take a look at the fact that you might continue reading with a closed stream reader

Comment: Maybe use a break statement?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
search = str.find(num, 0);
```

The type of `search` is `int` but the return type of `find()` is `std::size_t` so you have a mistmatch of types. Thus you have to work out what happens when the value is out of range (what is the value of std::string::npos?).

Secondly the value returned is the position of the first match (or std::string::npos). So if it was found I don't expect the result to be less than zero!

```
if (search <= 0) // So this is not going to work.
```